# Why MyPaint gets freezed when I try to switch brush?

Tags: linux, debian, fedora, freeze, drawing

MyPaint gets freezed when I try to switch brush. I have tried both the distributions debian 11, and fedora 35, not ubuntu, but debian is similar. Version 1 used to work. Any ideas?

```
(mypaint:12604): Gdk-WARNING **: 12:11:08.411: Window 0x3e27ba0 is already mapped at the time of grabbing. gdk_seat_grab() should be used to simultanously grab input and show this popup. You may find oddities ahead.
```

It also happens to others: https://github.com/mypaint/mypaint/issues/1125

Comment: I'm using krite now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to the mypaint man page you can use the `--logfile=FILE` argument for logging to a file. Strangely this won't work on my system, instead it logs to stdout.

It is also possible to get a full python trace with the `--trace` argument.

Comment: I have not even saved any files for this problem.

Comment: I got this on the console  `(mypaint:12604): Gdk-WARNING **: 12:11:08.411: Window 0x3e27ba0 is already mapped at the time of grabbing. gdk_seat_grab() should be used to simultanously grab input and show this popup. You may find oddities ahead.`

Comment: I looks like it is not only my case: https://github.com/mypaint/mypaint/issues/1125